# What is the best way to divert an IP address between two remote locations?

Tags: domain-name-system, failover, pbx, mpls, p2p

I would like to ask the community thoughts on the following.

I have two data centers, one up 'Norf, and one down South

Both are isolated in terms of network, but both have public IPs on a dedicated private circuit.

There is no MPLS between the two sites.

I run a hosted PBX service and want to be able to divert traffic from our South platform to the one up 'Norf causing only minimal downtime (as I realise there is no way of having zero downtime).

Suggestions I have come up with include HSRP on a P2P layer 2 link, or DNS failover with automatic monitoring.

I don't have a P2P link between the two locations but want to know if anybody has any other ideas that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer your are looking for but more of a suggestion when dealing with VoIP. After dealing with DNS headaches, route propagation issues and split brain issues, I would strongly suggest looking to your PBX vendor for a solution at that layer and let your endpoints know they have multiple ways to get dialtone.

This way you are not dependent on other services or appliance and can work with a single vendor to troubleshoot and test.

We used multiple softswitches all active and diverse and that list was given out via dns to endpoints. End points could register and rollover as needed allowing the system to handle not only an outage on our end but internet routing and peering issues where the customer's internet provide may not be able to reach one of our datacenters.